# Parenthese in returned string

Tags: jquery

I'm having an issue with a random parentheses displaying on my site. 
I have a code showing whether the user is online or offline, and it works perfectly when is user is online, displaying "X is online". But when the user is offline a random bracket will appear in the middle of the text like this: "X is (Offline". I tried some different things I found online like this

```
<script>
$('#usernamecrop').text(function (_,txt) {
    return txt.slice(0, -1);
});
</script>
```

but that makes it say "X is Onlin" and "X is (Offlin"

I also tried something like

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('status').val() == 'False'){
        return; }
    else {$('status').text(function (_,txt) {
    return txt.slice(0, -1);});
     }
    }
});
</script>
```

but that just doesn't work at all. 
I'm not very good at JavaScript, so can anyone identify an issue in this code?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change to**

```
<script>

// Also you have the jQuery selector to 'status'...that will not select anything. 
// I also returned something for the if statement.

$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('#status').val() == 'False') {
        return 'false'; 
    } else {
        $('#status').text(function (_,txt) {
            return txt.slice(0, -1);
        });
    }    
});

</script>
```

A good way to avoid errors is to write beautiful code.

Also I am not sure what values you're returning to.

Comment: It's still not working though. Nothing really happens.